# Special Page Background - Static, Tiled

Tags: css, html, static, background-image, tile

Okay lets say I have a cooled tiled background like on this website.
http://www.leeslights.com/colors-shapes-sizes-and-prices.html 
How would I make it so that the image tiles to the browser, but once it has done that it would become static, like the background is one this website.
http://www.worshipatthemountaintop.org/

Comment: All tiles must be one image and then you set `background-size : contain`
More infos here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below will work, it works on the tiled star image site, just replace what's in the brackets with your own image

```
background:url('ewExternalFiles/space_bg.gif')repeat fixed center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution to this is creating a separate div for page background with fixed position and full view size. Here is a [Pen](http://codepen.io/czoka/pen/emQzaj)

HTML:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <!-- and any other page content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/6/");
  background-size: tiled;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Some styling for the content:

```
div.content {
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px auto 60px auto;
}
```